# MSChart how to change spacing between dashes of a series

Tags: c#, .net, charts, series

I have got a series with a dashed line made with:

```
tmpChart.Series["function"].BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Dash;
```

But how can I change the spacing beween the dashes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a little workaround to do it with alpha-sections:

```
    private void SetChartTransparency(Chart chart, string Seriesname)
    {
        bool setTransparent = true;
        int numberOfPoints = 3;          
        chart.ApplyPaletteColors();
        foreach (DataPoint point in chart.Series[Seriesname].Points)
        {
            if (setTransparent)
                point.Color = Color.FromArgb(0, point.Color);
            else
                point.Color = Color.FromArgb(255, point.Color);
            numberOfPoints = numberOfPoints - 1;
            if (numberOfPoints == 0)
            {
                numberOfPoints = 3;
                setTransparent = !setTransparent;
            }         
        }     
    }
```